# Postgresql: how do I manage a list of columns for use in SELECT ... AS and INSERT queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is a more efficient and stable (defined only once) method of picking out a list of columns for use in INSERT and SELECT statements?  Specifically, I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO "mytable"("column") VALUES
('col1'),
('col2'),
('col3'),
...
```

And also a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc(args)
) AS (
"col1" text,
"col2" text,
"col3' text,
...
```

with the point being that I would like to define "col1", "col2", etc. elsewhere, somehow (function? table? combination?) only once, and use that list of columns in my queries.  This way, I define the columns in one place only, and, I shorten the queries.  It'd be fine to somehow use `mytable` in the `SELECT` query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `Composite Types`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/rowtypes.html